# Recursively search and extract substring from files in current dir using shell scripting in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, recursion

I want to recursively **search and extract** in all files inside my current directory, for any string that starts with "**B-0**" followed by **any number of digits**.

If a match is found, i want to extract it. But **at the same time, i want to extract unique strings**. For example - search might find B-05255 in 2 files. So i want to extract B-05255 only once (unique).

Once the search is done, **i want to allocate all strings to one final string comma separated as**:

FINAL_STRING = B-05255,B-05256,B-04152

Waiting for suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `grep`, `sort`, `tr` combination:

```
FINAL_STRING=$(grep -rIhEo '\bB-0[[:digit:]]*' . | sort -u | tr '\n' ',')
echo "${FINAL_STRING%,*}"
```

`grep` options used are:

- `r` - recursive
- `I` - ignore binary files
- `h` - omit filename in output
- `E` - extended regex
- `o` - only print matched output

Comment: It is giving me what i want but there is also some undesirable text as shown below:


FINAL_STRING='B-02802,B-02803,B-02804,B-02805,B-02806,B-02807,B-02813,B-02815,B-02988,B-03069,B-03071,B-03072,B-03073,B-04152,B-05255,B-05256,Binary file ./src/test/resources/images/12345.tif matches,Binary file ./src/test/resources/images/1253516.tif matches,Binary file ./src/test/resources/images/1261809.tif matches,Binary file ./src/test/resources/images/179822444.tif matches

Comment: Howcome these .tif files are getting extracted in FINAL_STRING.

Comment: That means inside your directory you also have some binary files like `./src/test/resources/images/12345.tif`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `-r` (recursive) :

```
GREP_OPTIONS="" /bin/grep -ohr '\bB-0[0-9]*' . | tr $'\n' ','
```

This iterates recursively trough the currently directory and searches for the pattern in every file. The option `-o` extracts only the matched strings (not the whole line). Note that I'm using the escape sequence `\b` which stands for *word boundary* (Because you said: "... that starts with ...")

However `grep` will print each result on a separate line. I'm piping the results to `tr` to replace newlines by commas.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I have used your command like this:     RESULT_STRING=$(grep -o -r 'B-0[0-9]*' .) but it is giving output like this:       /fastrack/SETA6LowestPriceOfSeasonTest.java:B-05255     also multiple lines are shown for B-05255

Comment: My requirement is that i want only unique B-05255 string to be returned. No file name required.

Comment: Used command exactly provided by you. Still giving filenames along with strings that i want comma separated and duplicate. Output:


./test/unstablefiles/DashboardTaskImageReadyToBePrintedTest.java:B-02988,./test/unstablefiles/DashboardTaskImageReadyToBePrintedTest.java:B-02988,./test/unstablefiles/DashboardTaskImageReadyToBePrintedTest.java:B-02988,./titan/test/unstablefiles/DashboardTaskImageReadyToBePrintedTest.java:B-02988,./regtests/functional/stella3/fastrack/SETA6LowestPriceOfSeasonTest.java:B-05255,

Comment: Use `-h` for *no filename* (Should be default, I don't know why it is not default in *your* grep)